# ubuntu 13.10 bonding

Tags: networking, server

So, I have installed ubuntu 13.10 and trying to aggregate couple of my interfaces.
First that seems to me suspicious is that my interfaces are called in unusual way: p1p1 and p1p2 instead of usual eth0 & eth1.
so, I installed ifenslave, and tried to make bond0 interface and that is my second point:
when I boot my server there is a lot of fail messages saying "cannot create virtual network interface". networking service is stopped and fail to start for unknown reasons.
ifconfig -a show me all of my interfaces including bond0, but when I'm trying to ifup bond0 it says: /etc/networking/interfaces:21: unknown address type. Whats the reason of this problem? I read a lot of manuals, do whatever it written about but in vain.
Here's my /etc/networking/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto p1p1
#iface p1p1 inet static
#       address 10.0.9.15
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       network 10.0.9.0
#       broadcast 10.0.9.255
#       gateway 10.0.9.254
#       # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
#       dns-nameservers 10.0.9.6
#       dns-search school49-tver.ru

auto bond0
iface bond0 itet static
        address 172.16.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 172.16.0.0
        broadcast 172.16.0.127
        gateway 172.16.0.1
        dns-nameservers 10.0.9.6
        dns-search school49-tver.ru
        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond-slaves p1p1 p1p2‏
#auto bond0.40

auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
auto p1p2
iface p1p2 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
```

Comment: Is that a typo? "iface bond0 itet static" where it should be _inet_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem suddenly solved.
follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) instruction.
here's my working configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto p1p2
iface p1p2 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 172.16.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 172.16.0.0
        broadcast 172.16.0.127
        gateway 172.16.0.1

        bond-mode 4
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond-slaves p1p1 p1p2
```